# Client Server architecture design

Tags: database, architecture, client-server

The application is a client server model.

Client application has local database which the customer will use on their day to day transaction.

The server holds another database which have consolidated information from client along with some other key things.

Periodically, client and server need to communicate for: data migration, accessing data from server (which is not available at client side), etc.

Neither the client or the server has static IP addresses.

How to make sure client can connect to the server seamlessly?

To put everything at a single location (e.g. in cloud or at a datacentre) is not an option due to the business requirements.

Comment: Your requirement sounds more like P2P applications instead of Client Server. And may I know the reason behind "Also we can not put client and server database and services at one location (for e.g. in cloud or at a datacentre) due to the business requirements"

Comment: This requirement came from customer who only want their data on their premises :| (yeah dont ask!!!)

Answer (score 3):

If there's a single server, why can't it have a static IP?

Does it always have an outside-visible IP? Then dynamic DNS is for you - the server notifies DNS servers on IP address change.

If neither of them have a publicly reacheable address, you'll need a mediator (proxy), which has. Now, this mediator will either know of the data, or the data will be encrypted to it.

Such a mediator could be anything, for example XMPP server, where the server would be assigned a specific JID, like server@mydomain, and clients would be assigned to their own IDs (like, customername@mydomain), or perhaps some PubSub solution, or it could be even an e-mail based solution (yeah, that's dirty), where both the client and server periodically read their mailboxes.

I guess also most ESB solutions would do.

The main thing is, in order to create a client-server architecture on the internet, the server (or a mediator which helps to reach the server with its own application-specific protocol) must be publicly reachable.

Comment: I have thought about doing this in DynDNS way. difference would be that the proxy server will be sitting between two peers and two peers will have a client running which notify the proxy about their IPs. When two peers wishes to communicate then they will ask proxy about what is the another peer's IP address and the proxy will give most uptodate ip.

Comment: If you have something stable sitting between them, you may just as well build a bi-directional channel in that something, like a VPN, but it's true that this way communication doesn't have to flow through that something, it's only a name registry.